# How to improve the performance of VideoTrim?

Tags: performance-tuning, video

I will trim my video into the small segments, and then join them again into one video.
But the performance is too slow.

For example, I have 100 segments of video, each segment has 8 seconds.
It takes me 30 minutes to render the final video. How to reduce the time?
I have 15 minutes length video, and it takes me 1h to render the final video.

Here is the sample code:

```
v = Video[videoname];
segments = Range[1,3000,8];
VideoJoin[VideoTrim[v, # + {-4, 4} & /@ segments]]
```

Comment: A few questions: what encoding does the original file have? and what is the encoding of the result?

Comment: The original file is mp4, H264 encoding. The result should be also in mp4.